# git merge vs. git rebase when bringing aosp ics branch into master

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

Which is a recommended method when bringing aosp ics branch into master(my project main branch), git merge or git rebase?
(By the way I read [When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge), but still confused which is the proper thing to do in that situation.)

Answer (score 1):

> bringing aosp ics branch into master?

**merge** (first merge `master` into your  `aosp ics` branch in order to solve any conflict locally, then merge `aosp ics` to `master`)

A `rebase` is only interesting in your case if you didn't push your `aosp ics`, ie if you didn't publish the history of that branch to a public upstream repo.
Then you could rebase  `aosp ics` on top of `master`, again resolving any conflict locally, before merging  `aosp ics` to `master`.
So even with rebase, you would end up with a merge from  `aosp ics` to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

The quick steps to rebase the 'aosp_ics' branch onto master would be:

`git checkout aosp_ics`

`git rebase master`

`git checkout master`

`git rebase aosp_ics`  --or--  `git merge -ff-only aosp_ics`

**this assumes there are no uncommitted changes and no merge conflicts during the rebase. If there are merge conflicts just insert the steps for resolving conflicts during a rebase, and then resume the steps above.*gs